# How to dynamically Sum a range of columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to make a function that will be used to calculate what the Year To Date Revenue for my company would've been for the same period last financial year.

I have 24 columns that hold the last 24 months of data for each cost centre and revenue stream. The issue is that each period that goes by means that the YTD columns increase by 1 and reset at the end of the financial year. And as such the columns each month shift 1 to the left. So half way through the year i'll need to be looking back 18 columns to get the start of the previous financial year and calculate the first 6 columns from there. But when it's period 9, i'll need to look back 21 columns and then calculate the first 9 columns that come after it.

Using the AI column as a reference, i want to go SUM(AI(row):AI(row)) so that in the previous example it would shift the columns by -21 and (-21+9) respectively. So that it would then become SUM(N(row):V(row))

[image: Shows the rows that will shift each month]

The highlighted columns will shift left each month. The AO and AP cells are will be updated each time and will tell the function how far to shift along the columns and how many to sum.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `INDEX` function to create a dynamic range, and `COLUMN()` to reference the column the formula is in.

Putting this together you get for row 2 you get

```
=SUM(INDEX(2:2,1,COLUMN()-$AP2):INDEX(2:2,1,COLUMN()-$AP2+$AO2-1))
```

Copy down for subsequent rows.

I'm not entirely clear on the offsets you want.  For a Formula in column `AI` the values in your example this will sum `N2:V2` - 9 columns.

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thank you